# Duplicate record search inside datagridview loop

Tags: c#, sql, for-loop, datagridview, duplicates

I record the records in the datagridview to the database with a button and I do the deletion. I wrote a method for duplicate records, the method works, but sometimes there is a problem in the loop. The method is as follows;

```
 void mukerrer()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                baglanti.Open();
                SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Select * from STOKLAR WHERE barkod_no='" + Int64.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["barkod_no"].Value.ToString()) + "'", baglanti);
                //komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", barkod.Substring(3, 13));
                SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();


                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    durum = false; // Kayıt varsa false
                }
                else
                {
                    durum = true;
                };
                baglanti.Close();
            }
        }
```

During the registration process, I call the method as follows, but I think the count operation is giving me an error. (dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1) but when it gives a warning once, even if I delete that record from the datagridview, it gives a warning again.

```
 private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            mukerrer();
            if (durum == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    baglanti.Open();
                    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("insert into STOKLAR(barkod_no,toplam_paket_no,paket_no,raf_id,create_date) values (@barkod_no,@toplam_paket_no,@paket_no,@raf_id,@create_date)", baglanti);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barkod_no", Int64.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["barkod_no"].Value.ToString()));
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toplam_paket_no", int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["toplam_paket_no"].Value.ToString()));
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paket_no", int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["paket_no"].Value.ToString()));
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raf_id", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["raf_id"].Value.ToString());
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@create_date", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["create_date"].Value);
                    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    baglanti.Close();
                }

                textRaf.Text = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Kayıtlar Eklenmiştir.");
                this.ActiveControl = textRaf;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sistemde kayıtlı olan barkod var!", "Bilgi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }      
        }
```

Comment: You mean sometime ` if (durum == true)` not happens and else condition happens? When durum is true and when is false?

Comment: If "True" there is no record, if "False" there is a record

Answer (score 0):

You should break the for loop after the durum == false.

Something like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        baglanti.Open();
                        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Select * from STOKLAR WHERE barkod_no='" + Int64.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["barkod_no"].Value.ToString()) + "'", baglanti);
                        //komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", barkod.Substring(3, 13));
                        SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
        
        
                        if (dr.Read())
                        {
                            durum = false; // Kayıt varsa false
                            baglanti.Close();                            
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            durum = true;
                        };
                        baglanti.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: And always use parameters for prevent sql injections.

Comment: The same is true for deletion, I tried the answer you sent, but I did not get the correct result in deletion.

Answer (score 0):

The same is true for deletion, I tried the answer you sent, but I did not get the correct result in deletion.

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    mukerrer();
    if (durum == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Kayıtlı olmayan barkod var!", "Bilgi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    else
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            baglanti.Open();
            SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("delete from STOKLAR where barkod_no='" + Int64.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["barkod_no"].Value.ToString()) + "'", baglanti);
            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            baglanti.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Kayıtlar Silindi", "Bilgi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;


        for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```